# How can I override a virtual function in a derived class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance, virtual

I am trying to build a zoo for practicing c++ and oop. I have made 2 classes, Animal class (the base class) and Bear class (the derived class). I want to have 2 virtual functions in Animal that I will override in Bear but CLION tells me that 'Function Walk did not decleared in class Bear'.

What do I need to change?

This is the base class (Animal) header:

```
class Animal {
public:
    Animal();
    Animal(string Name, int CageNum, string FoodType, string Gender, bool NeedTreatment);

    virtual void Talk() = 0;
    virtual void Walk();
    int CageNum;
    string FoodType;
    string Gender;
    bool NeedTreatment;
    string Name;
};
```

CPP:

```
Animal::Animal() {};
Animal::Animal(string Name, int CageNum, string FoodType, string Gender, bool NeedTreatment) :
        Name(Name), CageNum(CageNum), FoodType(FoodType), Gender(Gender), NeedTreatment(NeedTreatment){};
```

This is the derived class (Bear) header:

```
#include "Animal.h"

class Bear : public Animal{
protected:
    string FurColor;
public:
    Bear(string Name, int CageNum, string FoodType, string Gender, bool NeedTreatment,string FurColor);

};
```

and this is the CPP:

```
#include "Bear.h"
Bear::Bear(string Name, int CageNum, string FoodType, string Gender, bool NeedTreatment,string FurColor) :
        Animal(Name, CageNum, FoodType, Gender, NeedTreatment),FurColor(FurColor) {};
void Bear::Walk() {
    cout << "Bear Moves";
}
void Animal::Talk() {
    "Bear Noise";
}
```

Comment: What's the real error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define a function like

```
void Bear::Walk() {
    cout << "Bear Moves";
}
```

its declaration must appear in the class definition:

```
class Bear : public Animal{
protected:
    string FurColor;
public:
    Bear(string Name, int CageNum, string FoodType, string Gender, bool NeedTreatment,string FurColor);
    void Walk() override; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
};
```

Alternatively you can omit the definition, and the base class member definition `Animal::Walk()` will be used.

---

Also

```
void Animal::Talk() {
    "Bear Noise";
}
```

is wrong (or at last doesn't do what is intended).

A pure virtual function like `Talk()` from the base class, must have a declaration and definition in the `Bear` class, unless the class is intentionally left abstract.

```
class Bear : public Animal{
protected:
    string FurColor;
public:
    Bear(string Name, int CageNum, string FoodType, string Gender, bool NeedTreatment,string FurColor);
    void Talk() override; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    void Walk() override;
};
```

and the definition

```
void Bear::Talk() {
    "Bear Noise";
}
```

Comment: I want to declare virtual method at the animal class and implenent it at the Bear class

Comment: @YoavLinder As mentioned, what has a definition must also have a declaration at the same scope.

Comment: Then what's the reason to use virtual function? I can juat declare these functions in all the derived classes

Comment: @Yoav The reasoning for `virtual` functions is that you can call `Bear::Walk()` using an `Animal*` or `Animal&`. That's called _virtual polymorphism_.

Comment: You want to use the `override` specifier at the end of the declaration. This ensures that the derived methods class will be called over the base class version among other things.

Comment: If `Bear` declares (a non-pure override of) `walk()`, there must also be a definition of `Bear::walk()`.   Otherwise there will be a linker error from code that instantiates or uses an instance `Bear`.   To answer the original question, it is not possible for `Bear` to override `Animal::walk()` unless there is a corresponding declaration of `walk()` within `Bear`.   The point of a virtual function is to permit derived classes to override it, IF the derived class declares and defines its own version.

Comment: @FrancisCugler *"This ensures that the derived methods class will be called over the base class version..." It does no such thing. `override` is a specifier to the compiler to check if the function is virtual and that it is overriding a virtual function from the base class, otherwise emit an error. In other words, it checks at compile-time to make sure you are actually overriding a base class function and has nothing to do with run-time calls. See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override

Comment: @Casey You are correct; I used the wrong choice of word(s). I did say "will be called", It should of been "has been called". It helps to give the proper compiler errors within the debugger.

Comment: @FrancisCugler Almost. :P Again, it only has to do with declarations, not whether or not a function is called. "...has been declared" would be a better choice of words. :)

Comment: @Casey "... has been declared" yeah that does sound more like it.

Comment: @Francis I don't see the relevance of your comment regarding what's written in my answer anyways. You can always open a chatroom for you and _@Casey_ to discuss that further.